# Error message for TextField not shown (Vaadin 24.0)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

This is my code (fragment):

```
public MainView() {
    var tf = new TextField();
    tf.setWidth("30em");
    tf.setClearButtonVisible(true);
    tf.setRequired(true);
    tf.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
        if (event.getValue() == null || !event.getValue().contains("a")) {
            tf.setInvalid(true);
            tf.setErrorMessage("Error: input should be a text containing letter 'a'");
        } else {
            tf.setInvalid(false);
            tf.setErrorMessage(null);
        }
    });
}
```

The message is not shown.However, if i click the clear button it is shown. But after a new (invalid) string is entered, the message is not shown.

After entering an invalid text and press :

[image]

After clicking the clear button:

[image]

Comment: See https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/4804 for more information. TL;DR: Use Binder.

Comment: @Knoobie thanks, we cannot / do not want to use the Binder in this use case. So i will check your referenced page in more detail tomorrow